# Lable in toolbar xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, toolbar, custom-renderer

I am a new xamarin forms trainee
I want to add title, logo and back button to my page and make the back button on the right of the page, and make the title on the left of back button, where the logo on the left of the page.
I tried to use `Xamrin.Forms.ToolbarItem`, but is did not help me because ToolbarItem can not be label or text as you know.
and when I searched I found that I have to use custom render without find a complete answer.
so I came to here to ask your help.
thank you.

  -

---

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `"Xamarin.Forms Title View"` to do this.

https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Home/post/xamarin-forms-title-view-a-powerful-navigation-view

Answer (score 0):

This is might not the solution you expect but Xamarin Docs shows how to build your own page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating